# Is there any way to get all language lines in CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

In CodeIgniter 3 was ability to get all language lines as array with:

```
$this->lang->language
```

It is very useful for views - no need to list all the required language fields and just add all of them (from the loaded language files).

Is it possible to do that in CodeIgniter 4?

Comment: How are you using the language strings in views? Are you by any chance "sending" individual language strings from the controller to the view?

Comment: is this your question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035916/how-to-get-all-languages-data-in-codeigniter

Comment: @ZoliSzabó Some language fields I call from views with `<?= lang('File.field') ?>`. But some need to be passed from the controller, for example, "title", "subtitle" etc. (it depends of the controller).

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov No it isn't. This question is for CodeIgniter 2.

Comment: I do not get how `$allLanguageLines = $this->lang->language;` and then `<?= $allLanguageLines['title]` ?> is different from <?= lang('title') ?>. Am I not seeing something obvious?

Comment: There is no `$this->lang->language` in CodeIgniter 4. That's the point.

Comment: Does this section of the CodeIgniter 4 user guide help - https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/localization.html?highlight=language#creating-language-files

Comment: No. I've read it several times. This feature doesn't explained here. And the source code is also missing the required methods. I think this is not provided in the framework. The question is, maybe someone solved this problem for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Solution.

Create an App\Libraries Class and extends Language.

**App\Libraries\I18n.php**

```
<?php 

namespace App\Libraries;

use CodeIgniter\Language\Language;

class I18n extends Language {

    public function GetAllLanguage($with_class = false) {
        $result = array();
        $lang_arr = $this->language[$this->locale];
        
        if ($with_class == true) {
            return $lang_arr;
        }

        foreach ($lang_arr as $key => $value) {
            $result += $lang_arr[$key];
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

you can add method or something in this Libraries Class.

then Add this code in **app\Config\Services.php**

```
<?php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService;
use Config\Services as AppServices;
use Locale;

class Services extends BaseService
{
    //override Language
    //source code from system\Config\Services.php
    public static function Language($locale = null, $getShared = true) {
        if ($getShared) {
            return static::getSharedInstance('language', $locale)->setLocale($locale);
        }

        if (AppServices::request() instanceof IncomingRequest) {
            $requestLocale = AppServices::request()->getLocale();
        } else {
            $requestLocale = Locale::getDefault();
        }

        // Use '?:' for empty string check
        $locale = $locale ?: $requestLocale;

        return new \App\Libraries\I18n($locale); //override use Libraries
    }
}
```

then you can use in controller.

when I have two Language file.
(  Language\zh-TW\Menu.php 、 Language\zh-TW\Text.php)

```
$lang = \Config\Services::Language();
$lang->GetAllLanguage();
/**
array(157) {
 ["Login"] => "登入",
 ["BaseData"] => "基本資料",
 ...
 ["refresh"] => "刷新",
 ["AccountInfo"] => "使用者資訊",
 ["system_msg"] => "系統訊息",
 ...
 }
**/


$lang = \Config\Services::Language();
$lang->GetAllLanguage(true);
/**
array(2) {
  ["Menu"]=>
      array(26) {
        ["Login"] => "登入",
        ["BaseData"] => "基本資料"
        ...
      },
  ["Text"]=>
      array(131) {
        ["refresh"] => "刷新",
        ["AccountInfo"] => "使用者資訊",
        ["system_msg"] => "系統訊息",
        ...
      }
 }
**/
```

that it work.